# Conf-reg and ISSU

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-4500

I am trying to do an ISSU on Cisco 4k switch.

1) I booted both of the supervisor of the switch with the same image.

2) I also used the `boot system bootflash` command with both of the image names, setting the boot variable. So when I do `sh bootvar` from privilege mode I am getting both of the images name in the bootvar variable and the value of  the conf-reg as 2922

3) I have loaded both of the image the one which switch is running and the one to which i want to upgrade in the bootflash of the switch and also in the slave bootflash which may not be necessary.

4) I have also set one rommon mode variable `IssuSkipMatrixLookup=1`.

5) When i do `show redundancy` the switch is in the SSO mode.

6) When i do `sh bootvar` it contains only two images the one which is running and the one to which i want to upgrade.

7) I have also set the switch to be in auto-boot mode one of the pre-requisite of ISSU, From the `configure terminal` mode I have used the command `conf-reg 0x2102` but it is taking the value as 2922 by itself which I am unable to figure out, but i guess that must be fine cause the last value is 2.

But when I run the `issu loadversion`command I get this message

`%Active boot variable is Invalid.`

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: In some notes: Change config-register to 0x2102, save configuration, perform an SSO switchover.  After previous Primary supervisor is online as Secondary, issue an SSO Switchover again back to Primary supervisor. Future upgrades can now be performed via ISSU Changeversion.

Comment: @Rupin **I have also set the switch to be in auto-boot mode one of the pre-requisite of ISSU, From the configure terminal mode I have used the command conf-reg 0x2102 but it is taking the value as 2922 by itself which I am unable to figure out, but i guess that must be fine cause the last value is 2**. and why do we need to perform Switchover first to perform ISSU.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but we have hundreds of these things, and this was some of the notes from what Cisco told us we had to do. After the switchover you can use issu changeversion to do subsequent upgrades. I found this note is some reference documentation we have.

Comment: Well okay I will first perform the Switchovers first and then try the upgrade, but u got nay idea why the conf-reg value is setting to 2922 rather than 2102...?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Guys though I posted the question looking for the answer but I found the answer myself 
To set the boot system variable I was using the statement

```
switch(config)# boot system bootflash:Image.bin
```

Instead of that the command to set the boot variable is

```
switch(config)# boot system flash bootflash:Image.bin
```

and then everything worked fine.